# Visual Studio Team Services - Waiting for an available agent

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, azure-devops

This issue started happening to me this morning. I'm trying to run a build on Visual Studio Team Services but the build never starts, it stays like this forever:

[image]

FYI I have only 1 agent (Hosted). I checked the activity of the agent on Control Panel > Agent Pools > Requests but the agent seems to be available, i.e. there is no other activity.

I have stopped and restarted the builds 2 or 3 times with no luck.

Any suggestions? Is there any way to restart the build agent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by a VSTS issue which has been fixed now. Issue: [Issues with Hosted Build in Visual Studio Team Services – 4/15 – Resolved](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/2016/04/15/investigating-issues-with-hosted-build-in-visual-studio-team-services-415-investigating/)

And for your question "Is there any way to restart the build agent?", the answer is "NO" since you are using Hosted Build Agent. But you can [deploy your own build agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/agents/windows) which can be controlled by yourself and won't be affected by VSTS.

**Tips:**

Anytime you meet this issue, you can go to [VSTS Service Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/) to check if we are investigate this issue and the status of it.

Comment: still happening for me, is there anything I need to do to fix this on my end?
nope, just more issues -> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/2016/06/03/investigating-issues-with-hosted-build-in-visual-studio-team-services-63-investigating/

Comment: Happened for me today also

Comment: @PoulK.Sørensen It should be fixed now, can you retry? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/2016/06/18/issues-with-hosted-builds-in-visual-studio-team-services-617-investigating/

Comment: It started working again yesterday evening. (the link is saying it was fixed days ago?). Thanks anyhow

Comment: It did it again today, but this time it was enough to simply cancel and requeu. Was idling 1hours before i noticed it.

Comment: Got the "Waiting for an available agent" message as well. It appears that when you've triggered quite a few "Queue build..."s the hosted agent keeps you waiting longer for each next "Queue build...". Is there a limit for how many "Queue build.."s one can trigger before the hosted agent becomes "full"?

Comment: I am getting the same issue but when using Hosted Agent while creating a new Release "Waiting for an available agent. Current queue position is 1."

Comment: @ZeroOne It should be fixed now, can you try it again? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/?p=12085

Comment: It's happening again today... :/

Comment: While my dev release took 9 minutes approx. 30 mins ago, I have been waiting for release to production for 40 minutes already.

Comment: Just hit this issue today. Can't get it out of this state which is a bit annoying. It feels like this ability to kick the build agent to wake it up would be a nice feature.

Comment: Also hit this issue today so it is definitely not fixed.

Comment: I just ran into this issue. Appeared all of a sudden and now we cannot kick off any new builds. Goes into `Waiting for an available agent` more while the agent is green and in `idle` state. Anything else I can do to troubleshoot this or is there a workaround?

Comment: @xoail You can check this site when you meet this issue the next time: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/

Comment: I am having this as well.  Anyone find a solution?

Comment: @DanKaufman This issue should has been fixed for now, can you check it? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/?p=14696

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Thank you!  The issue is fixed.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I'm having this issue just now - build queued at 1. How can I overcome this as it's blocking our work?

Comment: Seeing this issue right now as well although it's not yet tracked on the blog. @EddieChen-MSFT It's hard to know where to file a support ticket for this, maybe instructions to do that could be added to your answer?