# Why is my brand new VSTS build using a deprecated "Hosted VS2017" agent?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have just created a very simple build on VSTS.  I used the blank template, chose the "Hosted VS2017" agent, specified the appropriate source repository, and added one task that simply does an NPM install.  Then I queued it up with the "Hosted VS2017" agent.

After doing this it is waiting for an available agent apparently indefinitely. Right above where it says "1 position in queue" it has "Hosted Agent" which is a link.  If I click it, I am taking to a page showing:
[image: Deprecated Agent]

Clicking on the "please migrate" text takes me to [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/news/2017#version-1-agent-deprecation-on-team-services), but that doesn't seem to be much help.  It seems to indicate that using the Hosted VS2017 would be the right agent.

Any ideas on how to properly set up my build?  I don't feel I need to migrate anything as I can just start from scratch.

Comment: It looks like this is similar to an issue reported nearly a year ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647734/visual-studio-team-services-waiting-for-an-available-agent

Comment: Have you got this issue fixed?

Comment: Yes, it magically fixed itself over time.

Answer (score 1):

For Hosted agents (Hosted and Hosted VS2017), it always update to latest automatically. And It seems a bug based on the screenshot you offered. And there has a bug report about [VSTS Hosted agent is deprecated](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/78072/vsts-hosted-agent-is-deprecated.html), you can follow up.

The latest Agent.Version is 2.119.1 currently:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the details.  I have the same agent version (2.119.1).  The bug you provided indicates that it should still run even when it mentions the migration notice.  That is not the case for me.  Eventually the build failed with "The request 6 was abandoned due to an infrastructure failure. Notification of assignment to an agent was never received."